# Neo4j: WebSocket connection failure

Tags: websocket, neo4j, connection

as the title says I'm facing the error:

> WebSocket connection failure. Due to security constraints in your web
> browser, the reason for the failure is not available to this Neo4j
> Driver…​

My neo4j DB is running on a Ubuntu Linux machine:

> Unbungu 20.04.04 LTS, Release 20.04

> Neo4j Community Edition, Version 4.4.8

I can connect to the db via:
http://localhost:7474/browser/

but not under
https://localhost:7473/browser/  or bolt+s://localhost:7687

I already tried multiple "solutions" but none of them work.
Here is what I changed in my config.

- dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0
- dbms.connectors.default_list_address=0.0.0.0
- dbms.connector.bolt.enabled=true
- dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
- dbms.connector.https.enabled=true
- dbms.connector.https.listen_address=0.0.0.0:7473

I also generated SSL certificates:

## Bolt SSL configuration

- dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.enabled=true
- dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.base_directory=certificates/bolt
- dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.private_key=private.key
- dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.public_certificate=public.crt
- dbms.ssl.policy.bolt.client_auth=NONE

## Https SSL configuration

- dbms.ssl.policy.https.enabled=true
- dbms.ssl.policy.https.base_directory=certificates/https
- dbms.ssl.policy.https.private_key=private.key
- dbms.ssl.policy.https.public_certificate=public.crt
- dbms.ssl.policy.https.client_auth=NONE

Any ideas?

*Edit: Typo

Comment: how are you trying to connect via bolt?

Comment: sry forgot to add it, I'm trying to connect via bolt+s:://localhost:7687

Comment: Is this a typo, 74747?  `http://localhost:74747/browser/`

Comment: ups, ye thats a typo... thank you for pointing it out